# Reaction energy $Q$

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

Really simple question, but I'm confused with it because of contradictions between sources (absence of clarity online vs lecture notes (says nuclear) and practise questions provided (uses atomic) )

In the reaction energy:
$$Q=E_{R,i} - E_{R,f} = K_f - K_i$$
Does one use the **atomic** masses or the mass of the nucleus (like what is needed for binding energy?) when solving for this?

Thanks very much in advance!

Edit: to supply clarity, I have the reaction:

$$N^{14}_{7} \rightarrow C^{14}_{6} + e^+ + \nu_e$$

I calculated $ΔB$ as
$$ΔB = (m_n - m_p - m_e + m_N - m_C) c^2$$
Where I have the masses of
Neutron, proton, electron, and the **atomic masses** of Nitrogen and Carbon, respectively.

I had to prove $Q = ΔB + m_ec^2$ with this, 
So I did:
$$Q = (m_n + (m_N -7m_e))c^2 - (m_p + (m_C - 6m_e))c^2$$
$$Q = (m_n - m_p - m_e + m_N - m_C)c^2 = ΔB$$
Where again, I have the atomic masses oh the Nitrogen and Carbon, take away the amount of electrons to obtain the nuclear mass.

The solution I've been provided uses **only** the atomic masses, rather than nuclear masses (which he says to use in his lecture notes) in the Q value to determine this relation. 
Any reason why using the atomic mass rather than nuclear mass misses the extra term?, or am I overlooking something completely trivial here?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is essentially a nuclear phenomenon, you only consider the mass of the nucleus.

---

In beta minus or plus decay though, where a proton converts into neutron and positron or a neutron converts into proton and electron respectively , you should consider the mass of electron/ positron because the electron/positron is formed **in the nucleus.** The electron/positron is quickly emitted (in order of 10^-7 s) because of its instability.

Comment: I've added a question where this problem arises, could you add further comment to it if you can please? :)

Comment: What you did is correct according to me. Maybe , the source has not considered the mass of electron because it’s mass/equivalent energy is very less compared to that of nucleons.

Comment: So I worked it out using nuclear masses as implied by the notes, and I don't get the relation- I just get ΔB rather than this difference of electron rest-mass energy. I've clarified my text a bit more to try and explain my problem, in that I'm unsure why just atomic masses are used to calculate the Q value as opposed to nuclear masses (as in BE, where you take the electrons from the atomic mass)?